# How To Transpose Every 3 values From One row To Multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, transpose

This can be potentially embarrassing but hey, its never too late to learn.

[image]

I am using Microsoft 2010.

I have the above mentioned row values in triplicates (scrambled control %) and I'll need to rearrange these triplicates into multiple columns with respect to the sample number (as above).

I am aware that you can easily every transpose these values into columns by selecting the triplicates and transposing them, 3 values at a time. I have a lot of samples and this will take ages.

So, is there any way to quicken this up, by selecting the whole single row and transposing the triplicates (3 values) into multiple columns?

Best,

San

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a formula or two.

This formula (filled right from E8 in the table below) pulls the sample numbers (659, 660, etc.) from the data at the top:

`=INDEX($2:$2,1,3*(COLUMN()-4))`

You haven't shown your row and column headings, so I've assumed the numbers are in row 2, and that the first column shown is column A.  You can change the "$2:$2" as necessary.  Also, the "4" has to be one less than the number of the column that the formula is in.

[image]

This formula, filled down and right from E9, copies the percentages into the proper locations:

`=INDEX($3:$3,3*(COLUMN()-4)-1+MOD((ROW()-9),3))`

Again, the row $3:$3 can be changed as necessary, and the "4" is one less than the number of the column that the formula is in.  Also, the "9" must be equal to the row that the formula is in.

EDIT: I'm also assuming that your sample numbers are in the middle cell of the three grouped cells.  If not, add or subtract 1 at the end of the formula:

`=INDEX($2:$2,1,3*(COLUMN()-4)-1)` or `=INDEX($2:$2,1,3*(COLUMN()-4)+1)`

I hope this helps, and good luck.

PS. If you found this answer helpful, please click the check mark at the top to accept the answer and remove it from the unanswered queue.  Thanks.